# Unable to access a protected variable from a friend fonction

Tags: c++

When I try to access a protected variable in two classes that have this function as a friend, it says that they are inaccessible:

```
class Item  
{  
private:  
    friend void Block::getMined(Mob& m);  
protected:  
    std::string Name;  
    double As;  
    double Ad;  
    double MineWood;  
    double MineStone;  
    double MineDirt;  
    unsigned long long Number;  
}  

class Mob : public Entity  
{  
private:  
    friend void Block::getMined(Mob& m);  
protected:  
    Item* Inventory;  
    const unsigned long long InventorySize = 18;  
    Item MainHand = e;  
    std::string Name;  
    char Show;  
    double As;  
    double Ad;  
    double MineWood;  
    double MineStone;  
    double MineDirt;  
}  

class Block  
{  
protected:  
    long long x, y;  
    std::string name;  
    char Show;  
    double MineSpeed;  
public:  
    Block()  
    {  
  
    }  
  
    void getMined(Mob& m)  
    {  
        unsigned long long i = 0, mi = 18;  
        while (i < 18)
        {
            if (m.Inventory[i].getName() == this->name)
            {
                m.Inventory[i].Number++;
                break;
            }
            if (m.Inventory[i].getName() == "empty")
            {
                if (mi < i)
                    mi = i;
            }
        }
        if (i == 18)
        {
            m.Inventory[i].getName() == this->name;
            m.Inventory[i].Number++;
        }
    }

    ~Block()
    {

    }
};
```

Errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error (active)  E0147   declaration is incompatible with "void Block::getMined(<error-type> &m)" (declared at line 158) myGame  C:\Visual_Studio\myGame\myGame\Main.cpp 8  



Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error (active)  E0147   declaration is incompatible with "void Block::getMined(<error-type> &m)" (declared at line 158) myGame  C:\Visual_Studio\myGame\myGame\Main.cpp 275
```

And there are a lot of errors saying member "Mob::Inventory" not accessible or other members, but the mehods are declared as friend.

Sorry if the text is hard to read, I have never used stackoverflow before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A first look, there are some syntax errors, at the end of each class you have to add semicolon. That's said, you're calling the function `getMined` from Bloc class which is (the class) declared and defined later, at this point you need a forward declaration at the top of your Item class `class Block;` and also your class Mob `class Mob;` and try this `Block::getMined (const Mob& m);`

Then it should work

Comment: Thank you. I have tried declaring the functions above, but i cant declare const Mob& m, because i need to change some elements of this parameter. And the semicolon mistakes are from me not copy pasting corectly. I have just tried to get rid of that method and define it as a function void getMined(Mob& m, const Block& b) and it seems to have worked(i redefined it as a friend in those classes). But do you have any ideea why it would matter if the function is declared inside or outside of the class?

Comment: you're talking about friend function? why we use friend functions? well friend function will give you the permissions to access the private data of your class and they have to be declared outside a class (friend functions) . If a function is declared inside a class it can access the data, if it's outside then it couldn't access those data unless it's declared friend. I hope this is what you're looking for?

Comment: not quite, lets suppose we have 2 classes: A and B, like this
class B{public: int b; void do(){*a = 3 + b;}};
class A{private:int* a; friend void B::do();};
For some reason it didnt work if i did this, but if i did something like this it worked
class B{int b;};
class A{private:int* a; friend void do();};
void do(const B& o){*a = 3 + o.b;}
Thats what i meant. Anyways thank you for being such a helpful person.;

Comment: ah I see now, friend function must be declared outside the class, you can learn more here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend